# Is it possible to take multiple mysql tables, then form a PHP array?

Tags: php, json, mysqli

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to take multiple mysql tables, and put them into a php array in the following type format:

Example:

- social profiles (say 3 columns)
- addresses (say 3)
- phone numbers ( say 3, work home and cell)

And then put them into a php array and encode in JSON so it comes out something like:

**EDIT -- JSON has been recently updated to valid JSON I would like to see in output**

```
[{
    "key": "111111",
    "username": "user1",
    "password": "test",
    "addr1": "address 123",
    "addr2": "address 321",
    "addr3": "address 444",
    "phone1": "1111111",
    "phone2": "2222222",
    "phone3": "3333333",
    "facebook": "sbh",
    "youtube": "sbh"
}, {
    "key": "111111",
    "username": "user2",
    "password": "test",
    "addr1": "address 123",
    "addr2": "address 321",
    "addr3": "address 444",
    "phone1": "1111111",
    "phone2": "2222222",
    "phone3": "3333333",
    "facebook": "sbh",
    "youtube": "sbh"
}]
```

**EDIT -- I have tried:**

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);
include '../db/dbcon.php';
$thekey = $_POST['key'];
$input = $mysqli->real_escape_string($thekey);
if($_POST) {
$q = "SELECT * FROM `users` JOIN `phones` ON `users`.key=`phones`.key JOIN         `social` ON `phones`.key=`social`.key WHERE p1.key = ".$input."";

} else {
echo 'failed';
}
//Start connection with SQL
$res = $mysqli->query($q) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$q]");
$array = array(); // initialize
while($row = $res->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
  $array[] = array(
    'key' => $row[0],
    'username' => $row[1],
    'password' => $row[2],
    'phone1' => $row[3],
'phone2' => $row[4],
'phon3' => $row[5],
'phone4' => $row[6],
'google' => $row[7],
'facebook' => $row[8],
'youtube' => $row[9],
'twitter' => $row[10],
'linkedin' => $row[11]
);
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
$res->free();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

**PHP code above has been recently updated to current efforts!**

Please excuse the bad json formatting.
If this is possible, can somebody please show me an example in php? Thank you!

Comment: yes its possible, what have you tried?

Comment: Your JSON snippet doesn't make any sense but yes, you can do that. There's plenty of information on http://php.net/ about querying databases and returning data as objects or arrays

Comment: yes consider joining your tables, then process the row into your array.

Comment: I added the php. I haven't fully tried to pull from multiple tables because I know I don't understand how.

Comment: But I have a project that I would like to do them in separate tables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pull information from 3 seperate tables, and aggregate each row. This would make each row contain fields from multiple tables. You are specifically looking for the JOIN sql command.

Something like this would do it for 2 tables:

```
SELECT p1.key,p1.username,p1.password, p2.phone,p2.addr,p2.addr2,p2.facebook,p2.linkedin,p2.twitter,p2.youtube FROM social_profiles t1 JOIN address p2 ON p1.memberId = p2.memberId WHERE p1.key = $memberidhere
```

Your example of values doesn't match your desired case of joining 3 tables, so I couldn't give you an example of the 2nd join because I don't know exactly what your structure is, but you could absolutely throw another join in there to bring another table into the query.

Comment: Bascially I would just want a format like: {user => social 1,2,3 + address 1,2,3 + phone 1,2,3}, {user 2 => social 1,2,3 + address 1,2,3 + phone 1,2,3} only in JSON created by php.

Comment: Hopefully that makes sense?

Comment: Sorry, im unsure what you are hoping to achieve as your json does not make sense. Can you please provide a REAL validated json string of what you are hoping to see? A real example will work better than your contrived example.

Comment: [
   {
      "key":"111111",
      "username":"user1",
      "password":"test",
      "addr1":"address 123",
      "addr2":"address 321",
      "addr3":"address 444",
      "phone1":"1111111",
      "phone2":"2222222",
      "phone3":"3333333",
      "facebook":"sbh",
      "youtube":"sbh"
},
{
      "key":"111111",
      "username":"user2",
      "password":"test",
      "addr1":"address 123",
      "addr2":"address 321",
      "addr3":"address 444",
      "phone1":"1111111",
      "phone2":"2222222",
      "phone3":"3333333",
      "facebook":"sbh",
      "youtube":"sbh"
   }
]

Comment: But all social media would be in one table, all users/password addresses in another table, and phones in another.

Comment: Updated code with my efforts so far. I tried the string you gave me, but it gave an error that said the syntax was incorrect. I formed what I have above based off what you gave me and examples from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html